# Python Kivy static Image(widget) optimization

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create simple (platformer) game with Kivy, but when I move an Image by changing it's `pos_hint` the Fps falls from 76 to 50-60. If my scene has a lot of Image widgets, changing one image's (other images are part of fon) position the fps falls from 70 to 18-20.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: I did not find the suitable solution.But ,static and mobile widgets had one parent when I changed it ,it give me +~5fps

Comment: Please show the code you're using..

Comment: Sorry,it seems the mistake in my own code,because i just have made simple sample where moving 100 objects(images) and it gave me 30fps. Must i delete this thread?

Comment: If the issue is a common mistake and the fix would be helpful to others with similar issue, it would be good to add your solution. If the issue was purely an problem with your own code, and not helpful to others, than you could delete your question.

Comment: As a general observation, if you have many moving items you'll be better off using canvas instructions. This is much more efficient than creating and frequently updating widgets.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Using canvas instructions helped me.Now Fps is about 52.I used  `with self.canvas:  
    for col in cols:  
        for row in rows:  
                self.box=Rectangle(source=self.directory+'BG.png',pos=[dp(row)*20,dp(col)*20],
                size=(dp(20),dp(20))`
  instead of  `with self.canvas:  
    for col in cols:   
        for row in rows:  
                self.box=Image(source=self.directory+'BG.png',pos_hint_x=dp(row)*20/Window.width,pos_hint_y=dp(col)*20/Window.height,
                size_hint=(.1,.1)`